# Passing data in angular2 component

Tags: angular

I have a angular2 component defined which is getting input from parent as below.

```
@Input() data: string;
 ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
```

In my parent page, I have the following

```
 <div class="row">
   <test-ui  [data]="data1">
   </test-ui>
 </div>
```

and the typescript in parent  has:

```
data1: string = 'Test Data';

OnaButtonClick(){
this.data1 = 'New Data';
}
```

My problem is that this is not getting the "New Data". The component is always having "Test Data" as input.
How can I get the changed data in my child component?

Comment: Where dose the OnaButtonClick function is? If you want to change the data in the child, you have to use [(data)] if the function in the parent, you have to pass the function to the child / set an output param from the child and get it with event in the parent

Comment: OnaButtonClick is in parent. I just want one way transfer (from parent to child)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. I just need to add a div which will initialize this tag after I get the required Data

```
 <div class="row" *ngIf="data1">
 <test-ui  [data]="data1">
   </test-ui>
 </div>
```